# html5 video source not changing in safari

Tags: jquery, html, src, attr

I am trying to change the source of a video in html5 but in Safari it does not change it the way I am trying to do it:

Here is my JQUERY:

```
$(".video").click(function (){
    var str = $(this).attr("id");
    var nww = str.substring(0, str.length - 4);
    $(".id").append(nww);
    $("#vid source:eq(0)").attr("src", nww+".mp4");
    $("#vid source:eq(1)").attr("src", nww+".ovg");
    $("#vid source:eq(2)").attr("src", nww+".webm");
    $("#vid")[0].load();
    });
```

Here is my HTML (the button to click on):

```
<div class="vid">
    <a id="http://cancunvideo.com/videos/localidades/cancun/spa/renova_spa_riu_caribe/assets/videos/Hotel_Riu_Caribe.mp4" class="video">
        <img src="http://cancunvideo.com/videos/localidades/cancun/spa/renova_spa_riu_caribe/assets/videos/Hotel_Riu_Caribe.jpg" width="230" height="120" border="0" />
    </a>
</div>
```

AND HERE IS MY VIDEO HTML:

```
<div id="mainVid">
   <video id="vid" width="640" height="360" poster="http://cancunvideo.com/videos/toyota_cancun/hossana/sources/template_toyota.png" autoplay="autoplay" controls style="display: block;">

      <!-- This is the path for the video. It's in webm format -->
  <source src="<?php echo $webm ?>" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
        <!-- This is the path for the video. It's in OGV format -->
  <source src="<?php echo $ovg ?>" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
        <!-- This is the path for the video. It's in mp4 format -->
  <source src="<?php echo $mp4 ?>" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />

    When a browser can't handle the poster fallback, it will show this P tag instead. Which happens to be the same static image.
    <p width="640" height="360" align=style="display: block; line-height: 1px;"><img src="http://cancunvideo.com/videos/toyota_cancun/hossana/sources/template_toyota.png" id="poster" alt="Poster" width="640" height="360" border="0" style="display: block;"></p> 
   </video> 
   <!-- first try HTML5 playback: if serving as XML, expand `controls` to `controls="controls"` and autoplay likewise -->
<!-- warning: playback does not work on iOS3 if you include the poster attribute! fixed in iOS4.0 -->

   </div>
```

And what happens in Safari is it changes all the sources but only to the first one called in jquery (MP4). And in Firefox it changes them all to the last one (.jpg).. any help here would be greatly appreciated. I have run into a wall! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$('.video').click(function(){...})`, try doing

```
$('.video').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        ...
    })
})
```